# How to start validating php form only after I clicked submit

Tags: php, validation

I am new to php and web development. I am trying to do a simple validation of text field. I want to display a red remark beside the text field after submit button was clicked.

However my problem here is: The php codes validates all input field the moment the page was loaded. How to validate it only after user clicked the submit button?

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        Name <input type='text' name='name' /><br>
        Email <input type='text' name='email' /><br>
        Age<input type='text' name='age' /><br>
        <input type='submit' name='Done' /><br><br>
</form>

<?php
    if(empty($POST['name']))
        echo '<font color="red">Please enter your name.</font>';
    if(empty($POST['email']))
        echo '<font color="red">Please enter your email.</font>';
    if(empty($POST['age']))
        echo '<font color="red">Please enter your age.</font>';
?>
```

I have several questions here:

1) If I want to display the error message right beside each text field, shall I write a separate php code beside **each** input field?

2) How to echo the error message only after user clicked the submit button?

I know this is extremely simply to many people here, but this is my first time doing something related to the web.

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. Change your condition like this: `if ($_POST && empty($_POST['name'])`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it still shows the error message the moment I load the page.. What is `$_POST` used for?

Comment: Why is the submit button outside the form?

Comment: @Barmar I pasted at the wrong place from my original codes, it is in the form in my actual codes. Have amended it above. thanks!

Comment: use javascript.. or you could use this http://parsleyjs.org/

Comment: @user3437460 You have no need of the `action` attribute if you're gonna have the form post on the same page.

Comment: @Alternatex I see. On top of that, I realize the moment I submit the page, it refreshes the page and all input in the text boxes are gone. What is the good practice to retain the text fields' values after validation?

Comment: try the script i posted in the answers.. that works 100% =)

Comment: @user3437460 Set the value of each input at the top of the page in PHP variables like so: `$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";`. And then print each variable in the `value` attribute of each HTML input field like so: `<input type='text' name='name' value='<?=$name?>' />`. The values will be set to the posted values and if the form hasn't been submitted yet they will default to empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to detect whether the page is being displayed in response to posting the form.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        echo '<span style="color: red;">Please enter your name.</span>';
    }
    if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
        echo '<span style="color: red;">Please enter your email.</span>';
    }
    if(empty($_POST['age'])) {
        echo '<span style="color: red;">Please enter your age.</span>';
    }
}
```

If you want to show them separately next to each input, you can write:

```
Name <input type='text' name='name' /> <?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && empty($_POST['name'])) {
    echo '<span style="color: red;">Please enter your name.</span>';
} ?><br>
```

Note that the variable containing `POST` parameters is `$_POST`, not `$POST`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, however I tried both `if($_POST)
` and `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")`. The moment the page is loaded, before I can click the submit button. The validation message shows up..

Comment: Is this page the target of some other form? If you just link to the page or enter it into the address bar, the method will be `GET` and none of that code should execute.

Comment: I think I realize what's wrong, I was trying to refresh the page, and it didn't work. I close the browser and open it, and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if post is send

```
<?php
        if($_POST)
        {
            if(empty($POST['name']))
                echo '<font color="red">Please enter your name.</font>';
            if(empty($POST['email']))
                echo '<font color="red">Please enter your email.</font>';
            if(empty($POST['age']))
                echo '<font color="red">Please enter your age.</font>';
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note:

```
<input type='submit' name='Done' /><br><br>
```

should be outside the PHP markup.
To display the errors beside each element, just move your if statements to the place where it should be displayed in the HTML.

Most developers use javascript for form validation. A quick Google will give you a lot information about this.

Answer (score 0):

try this i used your form working 100% =)

```
<script>
    function ValidateForm() {
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
        if (name == "" && email == "" && age == "")
        {
            document.getElementById("error_name").innerHTML = "Please enter your name<br/>";
            document.getElementById("error_email").innerHTML = "Please enter your email<br/>";
            document.getElementById("error_age").innerHTML = "Please enter your age";
            return false;
        }
        else if (name == "")
        {
            document.getElementById("error_name").innerHTML = "Please enter your name<br/>";
            return false;

        }
        else if (email == "")
        {
            document.getElementById("error_email").innerHTML = "Please enter your email<br/>";
            return false;
        }
        else if (age == "")
        {
            document.getElementById("error_age").innerHTML = "Please enter your age";
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" onSubmit="return ValidateForm()">
    Name <input type='text' id="name" name='name' /> <span id="error_name" style="color:red;"></span> <br>
    Email <input type='text' id="email" name='email' /> <span id="error_email" style="color:red;"></span><br>
    Age<input type='text' id="age" name='age' /> <span id="error_age" style="color:red;"></span><br>
    <input type='submit' name='Done' /><br><br>
</form>
```

Here is a pure php printing the error right beside the form fields

```
<?php
    $fieldErrors = array();
    if(isset($_POST['Done']))
    {
        $fields = array('name', 'email', 'age');
        foreach ($fields as $field) 
        {
            if($_POST[$field] == "")
            {
                $fieldErrors[] = $field;
            }
        }
    }

    if(count($fieldErrors) > 0)
        print_r($fieldErrors);
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    Name <input type='text' id="name" name='name' /> <span id="error_name" style="color:red;"><?php echo (count($fieldErrors) > 0 && in_array("name", $fieldErrors)) ? 'Please Enter your name' :''; ?></span> <br>
    Email <input type='text' id="email" name='email' /> <span id="error_email" style="color:red;"><?php echo (count($fieldErrors) > 0 && in_array("email", $fieldErrors)) ? 'Please Enter your email' :''; ?></span><br>
    Age<input type='text' id="age" name='age' /> <span id="error_age" style="color:red;"><?php echo (count($fieldErrors) > 0 && in_array("age", $fieldErrors)) ? 'Please Enter your age' :''; ?></span><br>
    <input type='submit' name='Done' /><br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, I will try it later. But I need to do everything in php.. :)

Comment: i added a pure PHP and html code on my second answer.. try it =)

Answer (score 0):

To follow the DRY system you can simplify your code a little and make it easy to adjust in case you add more fields to your form in the future. You only have to add your new fieldname(s) to the `$fields` array. It is also much easier to adjust the HTML in case you want another `class` or something.

```
 if(whatever condition you need)
    {
        $fields = array('name', 'email', 'age');
        foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
            if(empty($POST[$field]))
                echo '<font color="red">Please enter your ' . $field . '.</font>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a hidden input to your form.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        Name <input type='text' name='name' /><br>
        Email <input type='text' name='email' /><br>
        Age<input type='text' name='age' /><br>
        <input type='submit' name='Done' /><br><br>
<input type="hidden" name='form' value='wasSubmited' />
</form>
```

Then in the PHP script check `$_POST`:

```
if ($_POST['form'] == 'wasSubmited') {
 // here you can start to validate your form
}
```